# On which HTML element should I put page-global data-* attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I would like to pass some data from server to browser by putting it in an element in data attributes, like this:

```
<div id="globalvars" data-attr1="val1"></div>
```

But I feel that there should be a better element to use than `div`. `body` springs to mind, but I happen to generate my page using a Django template, and the `body` tag has already been emitted by the time I know the values of the globalvars.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what type of data you want to pass:

For a simple string, a data-attribute on an empty `<div>` might be enough.

If it's JSON data for example, you might want to place it as the text content of a `<script type="text/json">` and access it like this:

```
<script type="text/json" id="mydata">
    { "your_data": "goes here" }
</script>

<!-- ... -->

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('mydata').innerHTML);
    //do stuff with your data
})();

</script>
```

This is a common way to pass text to scripts and it's often used for templates but can also be used for arbitrary data.

The `type="text/json"` prevents the first `<script>` from being evaluated by the browser. That type attribute should match whatever you plan on putting in there. For plain text you'd use `text/plain` for example. As long as it's not a type that the browser will interpret as an actual script, it's fine.

Comment: However, introducing global state to your application might be a problem but that's another topic.